# Regular expression to find the number, 0 or decimal

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression which whill validate the number starting from 0 up - and might include decimals.

Any idea?

Comment: A bit of a vague question, IMO. A decimal number is, strictly speaking, a number expressed in the decimal number system, while I guess you  actually meant a decimal fraction (with a `.` or `,`). Could you clarify and give a couple of examples of valid and invalid strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple regex to validate a number:

```
^\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

This should work for a number with optional leading zeros, with an optional single dot and more digits.

- `^...$` - match from start to end of the string (will not validate `ab12.4c`)
- `\d+` - At least one digit.
- `(...)?` - optional group of...
- `\.\d+` - literal dot and one or more digits.

Comment: That doesn’t work on the decimal numbers accepted by compilers like C, Perl, or Java. You need to make it accept all of these: `42`, `42.`, `4.2`, and `.42`.

Comment: @tchrist - Hmm. I appreciate the enthusiasm, but isn't that a matter of decision? On every case you can decide if you need all of these literals - if they are valid for the OP *in this case* or not. I don't *need* to support C and Perl, do I? `.42` is nice to have and missing from my regex (`\d*\.?\d+` can solve it though, or something more efficient). By the way, in C# `42.` isn't valid - you can have a look [at the grammar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664812%28VS.71%29.aspx) under **C.1.8 Literals** > **real-literal**. Also, `42.` is weird `:)`

Comment: It’s not just C and Perl. It’s also awk, go, C++, Python, Java, and probably a *great* many other programming languages. It’s follows from the philosophy of being liberal in what you accept.  As for `42.`, that has been the standard way since time immemorial — or FORTRAN, whichever comes first — of distinguishing a float from an int. As far the rest, well, I’m like a good housekeeper in that I don’t do [ᴍ$ꜰᴛ] ᴡɪɴᴅᴏᴡ﹩: never had it, never will. It’s dead to me.

Answer (score 1):

Because decimal numbers may or may not have a decimal point in them, **and** may or may not have digits before that decimal point if they have some afterwards, **and** may or may not have digits following that decimal point if they have some before it, you must use this:

```
^(\d+(\.\d*)?|\d*\.\d+)$
```

which is usually better written:

```
^(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\d*\.\d+)$
```

and **much** better written:

```
(?x) 
^                       # anchor to start of string
(?:                     # EITHER
    \d+ (?: \. \d* )?   #   some digits, then optionally a decimal point following by optional digits
  |                     # OR ELSE
    \d*     \. \d+      #   optional digits followed then a decimal point and more digits
)                       # END ALTERNATIVES
$                       # anchor to end of string
```

If your regex compiler doesn’t support `\d`, or also depending on how Unicode-aware your regex engine is if you should prefer to match only ASCII digits instead of anything with the Unicode `Decimal_Number` property (shortcut `Nd`) — that is, anything with the `Numeric_Type=Decimal` property — then you might wish to swap in `[0-9]` for all instances above where I’ve used `\d`.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
^[0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?$
```

It will match any number starting with 0 and then any number, maybe a , or . and any number

Comment: This one doesn't seem to like 0

Comment: This now forces a leading zero?

Comment: Yes, it will force a leading zero, then any number and could end with a decimal.

Comment: Hmm, yes, maybe I misunderstood the OP question with starting from 0, I took it as a 'with'... updated my answer.

Comment: +1 unless I missed some of the answer edits part of the comments to this answer are wrong. very good point to mention that , and . are valid decimal separators depending on locale

Answer (score 0):

I always use [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to build my regular expressions. It is sort of drag-and-drop and has a live-preview of your regex and the result.

It'll look something like ^0[,.0-9]*

Comment: This one really doesn't do - as it validates the following : '0.5a', which contains the letter

Comment: Well, yeah, that why I said _something like_, and not "This is the solution:" ;-)

Comment: That validates `0,42.,...,,.12.411...,,.42,,1,,,1,,42McGillicuddy`, which surely is no help at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$
```

Note that with this expression 0.1 will be valid but .1 won't.

Answer (score -1):

```
'/^([0-9\.]+)$/'
```

will match if the test string is a positive decimal number